# download a file from url - Javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There's a CSV file uploaded to the server that I want to parse using javascript/jquery.

I'm trying to get the file using ajax call but it's always giving me error.:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://1fichier.com/?w5hfqz60tk&_=1474818392318. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

```
$.ajax({
        url:'https://1fichier.com/?w5hfqz60tk',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text",

        success: function (data){
          parseFile(data);

        },
        error:function(e){

        }
    });
```

I need to run the above code in jsFiddle..  How can I bypass this error?

Or is there any alternative way to download a file?

**Update:** *I just found out that adding url like this: https://crossorigin.me/MY_HTTP(S)_LINK solved my problem but I'm looking for an authentic way.*

Comment: Hit F12 and look at the error in the console. Likely cross origin error

Comment: can you share the console errors?

Comment: You should at least `console.dir(e)` in your error function

Comment: error mentioned in the Q

Comment: _"How can I bypass this error?"_ You can try using [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I bypass this error? Or is there any alternative way to
>   download a file?

You can use `$.getJSON()`, [`YQL`](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)

```js
var url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'https%3A%2F%2F1fichier.com%2F%3Fw5hfqz60tk'%0A&format=json&callback="

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  console.log(data.query.results)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```